# Azure Functions - TimerTrigger - Error when ran locally

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-functions

I have an issue when I start Azure Functions project locally. I am using AzureFunctions v1 (.Net Framework). The error I get is following:
[image]

This is my local.settings.json:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "StorageConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    }
}
```

I googled the error without much luck.

What could be the couse of this error? Is it about configuration? Also, these are all TimerTrigger functions.

Thanks..

**EDIT:**

```
public class TimerPing: _BaseTrigger
    {
        static TimerPing()
        {
            Init();
        }

        [FunctionName("Timer_Ping")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
        {
            //TryRun(() =>
            //{
            //    ErrorHandler.InsertServiceLog(
            //       $"{SERVICE_NAME} - Ping",
            //       "ping",
            //       SensorType.Success);
            //});
        }
    }
```

Please note that everything is commented out and this error still presists. 
Also, in Output window on VS 2017 I get this:
 Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in mscorlib.dll 
And I am running this locally using Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.12

Comment: Could you please add your code in Function.cs?  It's fine at my side.

Comment: @IvanYang Sure, just a second..

Comment: @IvanYang edited..

Comment: Seams that something wrong in the Init() method, can you share it?

Comment: @IvanYang sorry, I can`t.. but the method is fine, I am 100% certain, since it only does one small thing, and when debugging it goes without error, plus the values that should be populated after Init() runs are fine. Any other idea? And thanks for taking interest btw..

Comment: @IvanYang It appears you were right, the error seems to be coming from Init() function. Thank you much. I will have to verify this with few scenarios, but it seems that Init() is causing the issues.

Answer (score 0):

From the error screenshot you provided, `The type initializer xxx in TimerPing.TimerPing(static constructor) throw an exception`, so you should check the Init() method in it. Hope it helps.